# Replace \x0D\x0A with a space in Unix. Sed

Tags: unix, sed, sybase

I am trying to replace with a space the line feed (\x0A) and carriage return (\x0D) characters automatically.

The characters appear in a table that I have exported with UTF-8 encoding from a database in Sybase, in Windows. I am manipulating the file in Unix.

So far, I was able to delete them manually in text editors, with normal search mode (not escape characters option), but I would like to run it for several tables.

I have used unsuccessfully:

```
sed -i -e 's/\x0D\x0A/ /g' file_name.csv
```

**Edited**:

```
sed -i -e 's/%\x0D\x0A%/ /g' file_name.csv
sed -i -e 's/%\CR\LF%/ /g' file_name.csv
sed -i -e 's/%\r\n%/ /g' file_name.csv
tr '\15\12'  '  ' < file_name.cvs
tr '\x0D\x0A'  '  ' < file_name.cvs
```

This is how a row of the table looks like:

**30,57786,'B1','Philadelphia Coll Pharm 1879\x0D\x0A','Leaves'**

Comment: Why `\x0D` and `\x0A` instead of `\r` and `\n`?

Comment: The `-i -e` notation is usually used with `perl`, not `sed`.

Comment: @tadman The \x0D\x0A are visible in the .cvs and also in the entries in the tables created in the database

Comment: A very common variation is the requirement to remove control characters which are frequently represented like this; but you appear to have the literal text backslash, letter x, zero, uppercase D etc, is that correct?

Comment: @tadman `-e` is very commonly used with `sed` and many modern implementations of Sed have an `-i` option which works similarly to the one in Perl.

Comment: @tripleee, that is it exactly: the characters appear literally. That is why I don't understand why I can't remove them with sed, just as I did with other kind of characters. For example, I modified successfully the same file using this: `sed -i -e 's/,,/,NULL,/g' file_name.csv`

Comment: The percent characters in your attempt would only match literal percent characters, which you have none in your sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text contains literal backslashes, you need to double them.

```
sed -i -e 's/\\x0D\\x0A/ /g' file_name.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily in `tr`, which requires octal notation:

```
 tr '\15\12' '  ' < file_name.csv
```

- `\15` and `\12` are octal for `x0D` and `x0A`
- The characters used to substitute those with are simply spaces as the second argument to `tr`.

Comment: None `tr '\15\12'     '     ' < file_name.csv` nor `tr '\x0D\x0a'     '     ' < file_name.csv` are working

Comment: This would replace the corresponding conrol characters with spaces; but the OP's problem wasn't with control characters. Anyway, you want `tr -s` to suppress repeats, i.e. replace sequences of these control characters with a single space.